# Geocoding from inside a Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am using `gem 'geocoder'` to geocode locations while saving to my database.
Is there any possible way to implement geocoding inside a rails controller.Means,whether I could pass a set of params,ie params[:lat] and params[:long] in my controller and get the corresponding address?

Comment: You want to get addresses from the locations you've saved to the database? or from another source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out

```
Geocoder.coordinates(address)
```

will return the coordinates of the address passed as params.

```
Geocoder.address("lat,long")
```

will return the address of the coordinates passed